# How to fix whatsapp showing Unable to load image data?

Tags: internal-storage, whatsapp-messenger, samsung-galaxy-grand-2

I am using a Samsung Galaxy Grand 2 phone, and now my Whatsapp is showing an error "Unable to load image data". I cant even change my display picture or down/upload media to it. Is something wrong with my memory because apps like Hike are not even working? Even Titanium Backup says "Not able to find any backup in storage" while trying to backup my data. And also I am getting "Insufficient space" error in UC Browser, even though I have a couple of GBs in my SD card and internal too. I have tried reinstalling, clearing cache, clearing data but nothing worked. And yes my phone is rooted.

Answer (score -1):

do the hard reset of your phone, also clear the dalvik cache from recovery mode.
It should be helpful for you.